# A link from inside application to be moved to ie but that same link should not be navigated to a browser i.e.,, inside application.

Tags: c#, url, webforms, webbrowser-control

My code:-

```
void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((textBox1.Text.Contains(".jpg")) && (textBox1.Text.Contains(".png")))
      {
        e.cancel=true; //browser inside application should not be navigated but browser is navigating

        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();`
        webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(textBox1.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        webBrowserTask.Show();
     }
}
```

My question is how to stop the browser from navigating ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line :

```
webbrowser1.Stop();
```

Comment: it doesn't work,i need to implement on windowsphone 7